# Metamask is not defined when it's connected to local network

Tags: metamask

I have Metamask connected to the local Ganache network, but I am getting the "No web3? You should consider trying MetaMask!" message, so apparently Metamask isn't being used. How would I get it to use Metamask?

[image: Metamask Settings]

[image: Checking Metamask]

Comment: "when it's connected to local network" Are you implying that `web3` _is_ defined when you're connected to another network?

Comment: web3 is undefined when it's currently connected to the local 7545 network.

Comment: Again, are you implying that it _is_ defined when connected to a _different_ network?

Comment: I don't know if it's defined when it's connected to a different network. I am deploying my smart contracts on this local 7545 network and I would like Metamask to work when it's connected to it. Metamask being defined when it's connected to a different network doesn't solve my issue with this current network.

Comment: But it changes the question you're asking. If you asked someone "Why doesn't my car start when it's cold outside?" they wouldn't consider options like "there's no battery in it," because that would equally be a problem in warm weather.

Comment: If your question is just "Why is `web3` not defined when using MetaMask," my guess would be that you're checking too early. When is the code snippet you took a screenshot of executed? Try moving it to `window.onload` (or `$(function () { ... })` if using jQuery).

Comment: I am running this in a node server.js file. It doesn't have the window object.

Comment: MetaMask is a browser plugin, so it has no impact on code running outside of the browser.

Comment: Thank you. Would you just run all the smart contract calls in the frontend code? I am using ReactJS for the frontend.

Comment: Generally, yes. It's the user of the app that should be making the contract call, so you need to make it from the client (where they have MetaMask running with their private key).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved:

Metamask doesn't only works within the browser, so include all the contract calling logic in the frontend code.

Answer provided by smarx in the comments

Answer (score 1):

Are you running your 'html' file as 'http://' or 'file://' ? Because, this won't work in file:// method.

Just verified it locally. I've ganache running on `HTTP://127.0.0.1:8545` and used `node js (app.js)` and `index.html` files.

index.html

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="D:\TestEth\capestoneEthILP\html\js\web3.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var web3js;
    if(typeof web3 != 'undefined'){
        web3js = new Web3(web3.currentProvider);
        console.log("found web3?")
    }else{
        console.log("No Web3!");
        web3js = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://localhost:8545"))
    }
</script>
```

app.js

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
var path = require('path');

// viewed at http://localhost:8080
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/index.html'));
});
app.listen(3000, () => console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!'));
```

Open Node js..

```
C:\Users\mk\Desktop>node app.js
Example app listening on port 3000!
```

And the console output was like this...

```
Not allowed to load local resource: file:///D:/TestEth/capestoneEthILP/html/js/web3.js
(index):6 found web3?
(index):1 Error in event handler for (unknown): TypeError: Cannot read property 'state' of null
    at CSRecorder.onQueryStateCompleted (chrome-extension://cplklnmnlbnpmjogncfgfijoopmnlemp/content_scripts/recorder.js:106:18)
inpage.js:9 MetaMask: web3 will be deprecated in the near future in favor of the ethereumProvider 
https://github.com/MetaMask/faq/blob/master/detecting_metamask.md#web3-deprecation
get @ inpage.js:9
(anonymous) @ VM82:1
ContentLoader.js:28 failed to get content script
```

Comment: It's running on http. That's not the issue.